# Cant bind to directive despite including it as an input

Tags: angular, angular-components

Going through the error message below suggestion 1 in the error message below seems to be my case. It is an Angular component, and it has a GcUser input. However I confirmed it is part of the module (the component behind the HTML and the user-detail component both import it). What else can I try to fix this?

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'GcUser' since it isn't a known property of 'user-detail'.
>
> 1. If 'user-detail' is an Angular component and it has 'GcUser' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'user-detail' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

**HTML calling user-detail component**

```
<table #dtuser datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerUser" class="row-border hover">
    <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Company ID</th><th>User ID</th><th> ID</th><th></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let c of userlist" [class.selected]="c === selectedUser" (click)="selectUser($event, c)">
    <td>{{c.firstname}}</td><td>{{c.lastname}}</td><td>{{c.companyId}}</td><td>{{c.user_id}}</td><td>{{c.acctid}}</td>
    <td><a >DELETE USER</a></td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>

<user-detail [GcUser]="selectedUser"></user-detail>
```

**user-detail component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'user-detail',
  templateUrl: './userdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [/*'./greencard.component.css'*/]
})
export class UserDetailComponent { 

    @Input() user:GcUser;
  ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since yours input variable name is 'user' you should use this name to bind value: 
`<user-detail [user]="selectedUser"></user-detail>`

Comment: Drat, I thought that was supposed to be the name of the module, not the name of the variable..... that makes so much more sense now